# facebook messanger reports error when message is copy pasted to many friends

Tags: facebook, messenger

Facebook messenger gives error message, when tried to copy and paste the same message to many friends. Is there any limit to send messages in the messenger?
Please advise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not an actual programming question. For Facebook end user support, please consult their Help section.

Comment: That being said, Facebook places limits on a lot of end-user functionality, if you use it “too much”. Individually sending the same copy&pasted thing to multiple users could easily be detected as possible spam.